# Drupal 7 - l() when used with bootstrap glyphicon causes double spacing

Tags: drupal-7, twitter-bootstrap-3, glyphicons

Please see the attached image. I'm not sure why I am getting this double spacing when add a glyphicon to a link created with l(). If I remove the glyphicons the text is single spaced.[image]

Here is my code that is generating the menu

```
"<div class='btn-group dropup btn-full-width'>
        <button type='button' class='btn " . $managed . " btn-xs btn-full-width'>Manage</button>
        <button type='button' class='btn " . $managed . " dropdown-toggle btn-xs' data-toggle='dropdown'>
          <span class='caret'></span>
          <span class='sr-only'>Toggle Dropdown</span>
        </button>
        <ul class='dropdown-menu custom-blue' role='menu'>
          <li>" . l(' View Progress','observations/view_child/'.$row->child_id,array('attributes'=>array('class'=>array('btn', 'custom-blue','glyphicon', 'glyphicon-tasks', 'pull-left')))) . "</li>
          <li>" . l(' EYFS Profile / Learning Journey entry','observations/select_observation_type/' . $row->child_id,array('attributes'=>array('class'=>array('custom-blue','glyphicon','glyphicon-th-large')))) . "</li>
          <li>" . l(' Reports','observations/reports/' . $row->child_id,array('attributes'=>array('class'=>array('btn', 'custom-blue','glyphicon', 'glyphicon-print','pull-left')))) . "</li>
          <li>" . l(' Notebooks','observations/add_child_note/' . $row->child_id,array('attributes'=>array('class'=>array('btn', 'custom-blue','glyphicon', 'glyphicon-list-alt','pull-left')))). "</li>

          <li>" . l(' Next Steps','observations/view_next_steps/' . $row->child_id . '/0/0/',array('attributes'=>array('class'=>array('btn', 'custom-blue','glyphicon', 'glyphicon-random','pull-left')))) . "</li>
          <li>" . l(' Flags','observations/view_flagged_observations/' . $row->child_id,array('attributes'=>array('class'=>array('btn', 'custom-blue','glyphicon', 'glyphicon-flag','pull-left')))) . "</li>

          <li>" . l(' Edit Child Record','observations/edit_child/' . $row->child_id,array('attributes'=>array('class'=>array('btn', 'custom-blue','glyphicon', 'glyphicon-pencil','pull-left')))) . "</li>
          <li>" . l(' Child Contacts','observations/manage_child_contacts/' . $row->child_id,array('attributes'=>array('class'=>array('btn', 'custom-blue','glyphicon', 'glyphicon-phone-alt','pull-left')))) . "</li>

          <li>" . l(' Attendance Record','observations/attendance_record/' . $row->child_id,array('attributes'=>array('class'=>array('btn', 'custom-blue','glyphicon', 'glyphicon-list-alt','pull-left')))) . "</li>
          <li>" . l(' Attended Today','observations/mark_attended_today/' . $row->child_id,array('attributes'=>array('class'=>array('btn', 'custom-blue','glyphicon', 'glyphicon-ok','pull-left'), 'onclick'=>'if(!confirm("Register ' . $row->first_name . ' as attending today?")){return false;}'))) . "</li>
          <li>" . $backup_link . "</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      </li>

    ";
}
$html .= "</ul>";
```

Answer (score 3):

If the font-size is different, you may need to apply different word-spacing, which can make the style-sheet code more complex if you don't plan ahead.

I added this (sass-scss):

```
.glyphicon {
    word-spacing: -0.5em;

    &:before {
        padding-right: 0.5em;
    }
}
```

In regular css this looks like this (not tested, but it's the same meaning):

```
.glyphicon {
        word-spacing: -0.5em;
}

.glyphicon:before {
        padding-right: 0.5em;
}
```

Check out the [CSS MDN Reference for "word-spacing."](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-spacing) I also had to add "position: relative; bottom: 3px;" on the before because my links were inline. I know you don't need that info, but someone else might stumble in and that tidbit might save them some time.